# Breaking contents of column in Excel

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV with number of deaths per county in the U.S. Here's an excerpt:

```
County totals,Total
New York City New York US,"15,597 confirmed"
Westchester New York US,"3,891 confirmed"
Nassau New York US,"2,869 confirmed"
Suffolk New York US,"1,880 confirmed"
King Washington US,"1,277 confirmed"
Cook Illinois US,"1,194 confirmed"
```

In Excel, how do I separate the county name from the State and US. I can't use text to columns because some counties have 1, 2 or even 3 words in their names. Same with the state names.

Comment: Since the only thing that presents a pattern here is the state name, then I would start with a list of states. Once you find that string then you know everything before it is a county and anything after is the country. Other than that, you have no other pattern to use.

Comment: okay. thanks I will try in Pandas to run pattern against it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments the state name could be used to separate county from country.  `re.split` can be used to locate a space-delimited state name.  I use space-delimited because "New York City" would otherwise split incorrect, but since it starts the string it isn't space-delimited.  This could fail if a county name had a state name with in it that wasn't at the start of the string.

```
import csv
import re

splitter = r' (Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|Arkansas|California|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|Florida|Georgia|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Mississippi|Missouri|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New Hampshire|New Jersey|New Mexico|New York|North Carolina|North Dakota|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Rhode Island|South Carolina|South Dakota|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virginia|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|Wyoming) '

with open('data.csv',newline='') as fin:
    with open('processed.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
        r = csv.reader(fin)
        w = csv.writer(fout)
        next(r) # skip header
        w.writerow(['County','State','Country','Total'])
        for row in r:
            row[:1] = re.split(splitter,row[0])
            w.writerow(row)
```

processed.csv given OP input:

```
County,State,Country,Total
New York City,New York,US,"15,597 confirmed"
Westchester,New York,US,"3,891 confirmed"
Nassau,New York,US,"2,869 confirmed"
Suffolk,New York,US,"1,880 confirmed"
King,Washington,US,"1,277 confirmed"
Cook,Illinois,US,"1,194 confirmed"
```